# What replacement batteries does a Lomo LC-A require?

Tags: battery, lomo

Different sources seem to recommend either the SR44 or LR44 batteries. (Unfortunately it's not listed on the official [LC-A specifications](http://shop.lomography.com/gb/cameras/lomo-lc-a-family/lomo-lc-a-new-packaging).) Which should I use?

Answer (score 1):

There's some disagreement about this, but after doing some research, I think the best choice is three SR44s. (i.e. the silver oxide version of the alkaline [LR44](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR44_battery)--though probably both will work, though SR44s might provide sufficient voltage for longer.)

Notes/references:

- Silver oxide batteries have [a flatter voltage curve](http://members.iinet.net.au/~fotoplot/accbatcc.htm) than alkalines.
- Via email, lomography.com customer service recommended "three 1.5v silver oxide LR44 battery on the original and new LC-A cameras" and shared a link to http://24hourbatteries.com/silver-oxide-s76-battery/. However most sources claim that LR44 is alkaline.
- The [LC-A FAQ](http://www.kataan.org/lomofaq/) says SR44 and specifies silver oxide, but then has a confusing addition claiming that LR44 is the same as SR44.

Comment: The naming convention for batteries is an [IEC standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_nomenclature#IEC_battery_nomenclature).  LR is a round alkaline battery; SR is round silver-oxide.  Either one will work, but the SR will hold a charge longer.  The FAQ is wrong about LR and SR being the same.